# UTF-8 URL Decode / Encode

Tags: java, jquery, spring, tomcat, utf-8

I instruct my URL to send an Ajax request like that:

```js
url += '/' + something + '/' + id;
var response;
$.ajax({
    async : false,
    type: 'DELETE',
    url: url,
 ...
```

My `removeId` is a variable that includes UTF-8 character. I will handle that variable at Java side like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void myMethod(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable String id) {
    ...
```

However `id` variable at Java side is different from its original because UTF-8 characters changes to strange things.

How can I send UTF-8 characters from JavaScript side and transform it again at my Java side (Spring 3 with REST, my web server is Tomcat 7)?

**PS 1:** Even I don't use `encodeUriComponent` it seems that my URL is encoding by itself?

**PS 2:** To make question more clear:

```
i.e. my id variable is araç and sent URL is: localhost:8080/sdfasf/ara%C3%A7
```

When I see that id variable has that value:

```
araÃ§
```

instead of:

```
ara%C3%A7
```

Does Spring (or Tomcat) automatically do it? Is there any way to decode it automatically when it comes to controller as a path variable (I mean without writing anything as like:

```
URLDecoder.decode(id,"UTF-8");
```

it will be converted automatically)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The id value you see seems to be decoded using the iso-8859-1 charset instead of utf-8. The encoding of the path part of a url is not specified in java EE and there is no standard api to set it. For query parameters you can use [request.setCharacterEncoding](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setCharacterEncoding(java.lang.String)) before accessing any parameters to have them decoded correctly. The `CharacterEncodingFilter` does exactly that but has no influence on path parameters.

To make this work in Tomcat you have to set the `URIEncoding` attribute of the `Connector` element in its `server.xml` to "utf-8".

All you ever wanted to know about character encoding in a java webapp can be found in [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps/138950#138950) to a similar question.

Comment: thanks for your answer and voting up. I just want to sure. I use Spring and did that configuration (didn't do anything with Tomcat) and I think that I resolved my problem. Do I miss something (I mean maybe I didn't resolve the problem exactly and some characters will give error too?) and is there any example for how to use request.setCharacterEncoding?

Comment: @kamaci: I did not realize that was your answer and that it already solved your problem when I posted my answer. Calling `setCharacterEncoding` did not work for path parameters with oracle's OC4j container, maybe it does with tomcat. Although that contradicts some answers to similar questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079152/charset-filter-causing-issue-in-parsing-utf-8-characters/8079547#8079547 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630748/how-to-enable-reading-non-ascii-characters-in-servlets/2630977#2630977

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer here: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?14063-How-to-set-setCharacterEncoding-on-Request

I did that configuration at my Spring side:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and it works fine for UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting page encoding on the page where you are embedding the javascript?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the page encoding is set to UTF-8 by adding this right below the starting `<head>` tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Also make sure the JavaScript file is saved with UTF-8 encoding. Check your text editor settings.

Comment: I have that line at my HTML and my Editor saves my page as UTF-8. I think it is an issue about sending a UTF-8 variable over URL?

Comment: @kamaci What does `console.log(url);` say?

Comment: @nathias Bynens it is ara%C3%A7 too when I do `console.log(url);`

Comment: @kamaci But when you `console.log(id)` you get `"araç"`? No way.

Comment: I logged to console encoded URI. If I don't encode it (at javascript side) and log it to console it is `araç`.

Comment: @kamaci Where and why are you encoding it in JavaScript? Your code sample doesn’t show anything like that.

Comment: I don't encode it right now. Just I tried to encode it and send to server(as  indicated PS 1) but result was still same. I don't encode it right now. Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript use:

```
data=encodeURIComponent(data);
```

for encoding data, and in Java you can do:

```
data=java.net.URLDecoder.decode(data);
```

Comment: In the question the id is part of the request path so it already gets decoded by the servlet container. Also, the `decode` method should be called with the second parameter specifying the charset to use.

Answer (score -1):

No need to encode the string on javascript side.
Java does not support unicode so decoding needs to be done there as:

`output = new String(input.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");`