# Non-ASCII symbols in path variable of Spring MVC application on embedded Tomcat server setup using Spring Boot

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, utf-8, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-7

I am building a service using Spring MVC set up using Spring Boot where I want to be able to have arbitrary unicode characters in the URLs.

By looking around the web I end up with

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Filter characterEncodingFilter() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
        return characterEncodingFilter;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Controller
public class WordController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/word/{word}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String greeting(Model model, @PathVariable("word") String word) {

        System.out.println(word);

        model.addAttribute("word", word);
        return "word";
    }

}
```

where the template "word" just prints out the word from the model.

When I start the server and enter `http://localhost:8080/word/æøå` into Chrome, the text printed on the response page (and in the terminal) is

```
Ã¦Ã¸Ã¥
```

which I think I recognize as a ISO-8859-1 interpretation the Danish letters `æøå` when they're actually encoded in UTF-8.

Looking into Chrome's net inspector I see that it actually queries `http://localhost:8080/word/%C3%A6%C3%B8%C3%A52` which indeed seems to be the URL encoding of the string in UTF-8.

Can anyone explain why Spring doesn't parse the path variable as UTF-8 despite this configuration, and how to make it?

There seems to mixed opinions on whether `CharacterEncodingFilter` actually solves this problem. At least, in another (non-Boot) Spring project of mine I use `web.xml` to register the `CharacterEncodingFilter`. Here it's used successfully to make POST bodies parse as UTF-8, but I coudn't make it work for path variables there either.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147837/utf-8-url-decode-encode/8153988#8153988) suggests that it should be configured in Tomcat's settings. If so, how is that done on an embedded server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the event of a brain-wave, adding the bean method

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(8080);
    factory.addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public void customize(Connector connector) {
            connector.setURIEncoding("UTF-8");
        }
    });
    return factory;
}
```

seems to solve the problem.

**Edit**

The `CharacterEncodingFilter` is still necessary for converting POST bodies.

Comment: Would that be a sensible default for the rest of the world as well? If so it could be the default for spring boot.

Comment: So do you need the filter and the connector change or only the connector?

Comment: The filter should be removed to prevent double-converting POST bodies (it makes no difference regarding the path variable). Thanks for following up on this.

Comment: Oh wait, I seem to have been fooled by a double mis-encoding. Will update the answer shortly

Comment: Well, `CharacterEncodingFilter` is still needed as the edit now says. I was fooled by viewing the response of a `@ResponseBody` method as explained in [this follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935969/make-responsebody-annotated-spring-boot-mvc-controller-methods-return-utf-8). It turned out that Spring parsed the body (which was really UTF-8) as ISO-8859-1, returned it as such, while Chrome viewed it as UTF-8, cancelling the error. *Sigh*.