# Make @ResponseBody-annotated Spring (Boot) MVC controller methods return UTF-8

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, utf-8, spring-boot

I'm building a Spring MVC service using Spring Boot and want to be able to return strings as plain text encoded in UTF-8. Following [this description](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/docs/howto.html#toc_4), I thought the only thing necessary should be to add the bean method

```
@Bean
public HttpMessageConverter<String> responseBodyConverter() {
    StringHttpMessageConverter converter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(new MediaType("text", "plain", Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
    return converter;
}
```

But the `root` method in

```
@Controller
public class RootController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/"/*, produces="text/plain;charset=UTF-8"*/)
    @ResponseBody
    public String root() {
        return "æøå";
    }

}
```

responds the string `æøå` in ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8, unless I uncomment the `produces` part, in which case it actually returns UTF-8. The message converter doesn't seems to have any effect here.

Following [this approach](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) I confirm that the bean has actually been registered. Besides this bean, I also register an `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory` and `CharacterEncodingFilter` as described in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926329/non-ascii-symbols-in-path-variable-of-spring-mvc-application-on-embedded-tomcat/20926767), although I don't think that's relevant here.

Can someone explain what the registered `HttpMessageConverter` actually does, and how to make `@ResponseBody`-annotated controller methods return UTF-8 without having to provide `produces` every time?

**Edit**

As discussed in the comments, for the accepted answer to work, I had to upgrade the version of Spring Boot from `0.5.0.M6` to `0.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` and, to prevent outputting a junk header, call `converter.setWriteAcceptCharset(false)` on the `StringHttpMessageConverter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default character set for the `StringHttpMessageConverter`is `ISO-8859-1`. That means when  a client does not request a specific character set, then `ISO-8859-1` will be returned.

If you want `UTF-8`to be the default character set then you pass it into the constructor:

```
converter = new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Calling `setSupportedMediaTypes()` is then no longer necessary either as `text/plain; charset=default character set` is added automatically.

Comment: I believe that is correct but it doesn't quite answer the question, since the code in the OP should also work. I think the answer the OP is looking for is "upgrade Spring Boot to m7 or a recent snapshot" (the feature in the docs he linked to is newish).

Comment: @DaveSyer **"Can someone explain what the registered HttpMessageConverter actually does, and how to make @ ResponseBody-annotated controller methods return UTF-8 without having to provide produces every time"** - The answer completely covers that, don't you think?

Comment: Hm it seems that while it does add `charset=UTF-8` to `Content-Type`, the returned text is still actually ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @HalleKnast What values do the `Accept` and `Accept-Charset` headers of the request have? And how do you know its `ISO-8859-1`? Don't you get `æøå`?

Comment: I use Chrome. The network inspection panel gives the request headers `Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8`, no `Accept-Charset` header. I know because when I tell Chrome to change page encoding from `UTF-8` to `ISO-8859-1`, the page changes from `���` to `æøå`.

Comment: The `Content-Type` response header is `text/html;charset=UTF-8`. Also, it's the same in Firefox.

Comment: Ok, following @DaveSyer's suggestion, I upgraded `spring-boot-starter-parent` to version `0.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` and now it suddenly works. But it then adds a rather insane length response header `Accept-Charset:[many, many char sets - makes comment too long for SO]`. What's the point in that?

Comment: @HalleKnast You should be able to turn that off with `converter.setWriteAcceptCharset(false)`. I'm facing the problem that the converter actually does not replace the default one, like stated in the docs. Neither do I have the mentioned `HttpMessageConverters` class in my jars :(

Comment: Ok that works :) I guess that as last everything works as I want it to. But why in the world does it write that header by default??

Comment: Can You post whole clean answer? How did You solve it? I see that comments above but cant understand it.