# Incorrect encoding when using @PathVariable in Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

In my controller, I have this method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/find-by-company-name/{companyName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public CustomerDto findByCompanyName(@PathVariable String companyName){
    return customerService.findByCompanyName(companyName);
}
```

When I use URL like this `/find-by-company-name/Mestská%20knižnica` then I get `Mestsk?? kni??nica` in `companyName` variable.

Is there any solution to this issue?

In **web.xml** I use:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-     class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926329/non-ascii-symbols-in-path-variable-of-spring-mvc-application-on-embedded-tomcat) has a solution when the underlying serve is Tomcat. If you are using Tomcat then your question is duplicate =), if you are using some other server/app container than you should look whether there is some way to configure URI encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to add `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` to **server.xml** configuration file, like this:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL should be encoded, like the space `%20` is. Then encoding will be ok.