# Tomcat/Spring - get parameters not decoded

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, urlencode, url-encoding

For some reason my Tomcat/Spring configuration doesn't automatically decode the GET parameters ( I assume it should be done automatically ).

Here is my setup:

```java
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/do-something", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String doSomething(RequestPojo req) {
        // req.getPhone -- is not decoded, ie might be something like 00%204 instead of 004
    }
}


public class RequestPojo {
    private String phone;
    // getter and setter
}
```

Here is the content of mvc-dispatcher-servlet:

```xml
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="false">
        <ref bean="customJsonHttpMessageConverter"/>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.onoff.controller">
    <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>

<bean id="multipartResolver" name="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1073741824"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="utf8"/>
</bean>

<bean id="customJsonHttpMessageConverter" class="com.onoff.util.CustomJsonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json; charset=utf-8"/>
</bean>
```

I've checked some suggestions before posting.
`URIEncoding="UTF-8"` is specified in *server.xml* in Tomcat.

Any clues?
Any help/suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related: [UTF-8 URL Decode / Encode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147837/utf-8-url-decode-encode)

Comment: `00%204` isn't the same as `004`. It's the same as `00 4`. Maybe your parameters are being doubly *encoded?*

Comment: Yes, sorry, it should be "00 4". No, my parameters aren't encoded twice

Comment: 1.  You do not need to configure a message converter for JSON.  As long as the Jackson Jars on are the class path this message converter will automatically be supported so I would remove that from the config.  

2.  I believe the "supportedMediaTypes" should just be "application/json" not "application/json; charset=utf-8"  If you are going to set this as the media type then you have to set that in the header as the ContentType value instead of "application/json"

Comment: 3.  If it still is not working I would try changing doSomething(RequestPojo req) to doSomething(@RequestBody RequestPojo req).  If that makes no difference then I would start taking a detailed look at the request because something is likely off in the way the content is coming in or the way the headers are being passed.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with @ModelAttribute

```
public String doSomething(@ModelAttribute RequestPojo req) {
        // req.getPhone -- is not decoded, ie might be something like 00%204 instead of 004
    }
```